# É necessário invocar as funções "ShowWindow" e "UpdateWindow"?

Tags: c, c++, winapi

Recentemente fiz um introdução a Windows API e já estou na parte de criar janelas. Numa das primeiras aplicações que criei tive utilizar de `ShowWindow` e `UpdateWindow` depois de criar uma janela, mas mesmo sem elas a janela continuava a mostrar-se.
Até criei mais janelas para ver se a sua invocação seria necessária e essas janelas adicionais também apareciam.

Então fica aqui a minha questão é mesmo necessário invocá-las? Terá algum impacto não fazer? Ou é só uma medida de prevenção?

P.S Coloquei a tag de C++ pois é um API também utilizado nessa linguagem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não sei como você escreveu a aplicação, mas podemos dizer que algumas funções já chamam estas funções citadas "automaticamente" o que tornaria realmente isto redundante.

### ShowWindow

Mas note que o uso de `ShowWindow` não é só para exibir a janela na hora de iniciar um programa, ele tem como "utilidade" mudar o estado da janela que está fazendo referencia, por exemplo, isto forçaria a minimizar uma janela já aberta:

```
 ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_FORCEMINIMIZE);
```

- `SW_FORCEMINIMIZE` minimiza uma janela, mesmo que o Thread proprietário dela não esteja respondendo
- `SW_HIDE` - Oculta a janela e ativa outra janela
- `SW_MAXIMIZE` - minimiza a janela
- `SW_MINIMIZE` - minimiza a janela e ativa a proxima que está no level maior pela ordem Z
- `SW_RESTORE` - ativa e mostra a janela. Se estiver minimizada ou maximizada ele "restaura" para a posição e tamanhos originais.
- `SW_SHOW` - ativa e mostra a janela na posição e tamanho original.
- `SW_SHOWDEFAULT` - Define o estado da janela baseado no valor `SW_` especificado na estrutura `STARTUPINFO` passado para o `CreateProcess`
- `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` - Ativa e mostra a janela maximizada
- `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED` - Ativa e mostra a janela minimizada
- `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE` - mostra a janela minimizada, é similar ao SW_SHOWMINIMIZED, exceto que a janela não é ativada
- `SW_SHOWNA` - Mostra a janela na posição e tamanho atual, é similar ao SW_SHOW, exceto que a janela não é ativada
- `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` - Mostra a janela na posição e tamanho mais recente, é similar ao `SW_SHOWNORMAL`, exceto que não ativa a janela.
- `SW_SHOWNORMAL` - Ativa e mostra a janela. Se a janela está minimizada ou maximizada isto restaura para o tamanho e posição original. Uma aplicação deve especificar esta "flag" ao exibir a janela pela primeira vez.

### UpdateWindow

O `UpdateWindow` atualiza a área de cliente da janela, enviando uma mensagem `WM_PAINT` para a janela se a região de atualização não estiver vazia. Isto pode ser útil para animações talvez, então você irá usa-la quando necessário para atualizar a renderização.

Não tenho muito conhecimento, mas ao que me parece estes são os objetivos, se tiver alguma duvida a mais talvez apareçam novas respostas, espero que por enquanto isto ajude.

**Documentação:**

- [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [UpdateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Obrigado agora já percebi xP. O tutorial que estou a seguir não explica certas coisas que no MSDN também não estão explicadas :/

Comment: Guilherme, você teria um link da documentação disso tudo? Agregaria bastante à sua resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto adicionado documentação  sobre o `ShowWindow`, meu inglês não é muito bom, traduzi as flags da documentação da microsoft, se tiver alguma gafe me perdoe-me, eu traduzi com o básico que conheço do inglês (que é bem ruim por sinal :p ), eu não usei o google-tradutor pois muitas vezes os textos perdem o sentido para mim.

Answer (score 3):

Só para complementar o que o Guilherme disse, se você perceber, na maioria das vezes no momento the chamar o ShowWindow dentro da WinMain você envia o argumento nCmdShow, esse argumento é a maneira que o Windows quer que sua janela seja exibida(já que você pode mudar o modo de exibição de atalhos), então basicamente ao chamar o ShowWindow enviando nCmdShow, você não esta exatamente pedindo para função mostrar sua janela, mas sim para mostra-la da maneira que o Windows quer.

Mas a janela não é mostrada na tela sozinha, ela só é mostrada na tela automaticamente se você criar a janela enviando a flag WS_VISIBLE, veja este exemplo:

```
CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Janela", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 250, 150, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

No caso acima ela é mostrada automaticamente, pois você enviou o WS_VISIBLE na função, ou seja, mesmo sem chamar o ShowWindow ela será mostrada.

Agora veja este caso:

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Janela", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 250, 150, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);    
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
```

Neste caso a janela não aparecera sem a chamada do ShowWindow, pois não foi enviada a flag do WS_VISIBLE.

Comment: Ah! Pensava que o `nCmdShow` era uma espécie de `argc`. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento  ;D